# Magento 1.9 Model override not working

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to override a model in the Stripe extension, but I can't seem to get it to work. Here is what I have so far:

Stripe config.xml

```
<config>
 <global>
  <models>
      <compiler>
        <rewrite>
          <process>Stripe_Payments_Model_Compiler_Process</process>
        </rewrite>
      </compiler>
      <stripe_payments>
        <class>Stripe_Payments_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>stripe_payments_resource</resourceModel>
      </stripe_payments>
      <stripe_payments_resource>
        <class>Stripe_Payments_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
          <webhook>
            <table>stripe_webhooks</table>
          </webhook>
        </entities>
      </stripe_payments_resource>
    </models>
...
```

Stripe Model to override path:
app/code/community/Stripe/Payments/Model/PaymentIntent.php

Stripe Model to override:

```
<?php

class Stripe_Payments_Model_PaymentIntent
{
...
}
```

My module's config.xml:

```
    <config>
     <global>
      <models>
          <dbcustom_stripe>
            <class>DBCustom_Stripe_Model</class>
          </dbcustom_stripe>
          <stripe_payments>
           <rewrite>
            <paymentintent>DBCustom_Stripe_Model_PaymentIntent</paymentintent>
           </rewrite>
          </stripe_payments>
      </models>
...
```

My overriding model path:
app/code/local/DBCustom/Stripe/Model/PaymentIntent.php

My overriding model:

```
<?php


class DBCustom_Stripe_Model_PaymentIntent extends Stripe_Payments_Model_PaymentIntent {

...

}
```

My module is active and is overriding a helper class. I have also tried flushing the cache multiple times. Not sure what else to try, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which error it show?

Comment: There are no errors, it just doesn't work. I use Xdebug so I can tell which file it's going to when the code runs, and it keeps going into the original file to run and not the new one I setup.

Comment: share the code wht write into this one Stripe_Payments_Model_PaymentIntent

Comment: Have you added a `<depends>` node to your modules xml to load your module after `Stripe_Payments`?

Comment: Yeah, I added depends, still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<paymentIntent>` or `<payment_intent>` (it’s probably the first form with an uppercase *i*) instead of `<paymentintent>` in your module’s `config.xml`.

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thanks.